# Attaching different eventListeners for each item in for-of-loop

Tags: javascript, loops, fetch, addeventlistener, for-of-loop

For this exercise I am trying to create a mailbox mostly based on javascript.
After all the emails are fetched, I display them with a for-of-loop.
What I need to do now is provide an event listener to each email that runs the "show_email" function when I click on the mail.

Unfortunately when I run this code and then try to click on an email, it always loads the email with the email.id that is 1, instead of the email with the email.id according to the loop position.

Right now I have no idea how to fix this. Thanks for any help!

```
function inbox() {
  console.log('running function inbox');
  fetch('/emails/inbox')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(emails => {
    // looping through all mails to display them on the screen
    for (email of emails){
      const element = document.createElement('div');  
      element.innerHTML = `<div id="emails-item">
        <span id="emails-address">${email.sender}</span>
        <span id="emails-subject">${email.subject}</span>
        <span id="emails-timestamp">${email.timestamp}</span>
      </div>`;
      // Link to open individual email (here it does not do what I want)
      element.addEventListener('click', () => show_email(email.id));
      document.querySelector('#emails-view').append(element);
    }
    
  });
}

function show_email(id) {
  console.log(`Email ${id} is loaded...`)
}
```

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**. Use a class instead

Comment: So each email has a unique id, that is intended this way. The thing that is not working is actually opening this right email with that id Instead it always opens the email with id of 1. But thanks @Andreas! :)

Comment: At first, `addEventListener` expects the second argument being a function reference, you're passing `undefined`. To pass an unique argument to an event listener, you've to wrap the `show_email` call into an anonymous function. See the linked dup for further details.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu. What exactly is the "linked dup"? Sorry I am new here 

Comment: There's a big banner having a link at the top of the question.

Comment: Alright I was able to solve the problem by just defining a variable "id" inside of the loop. and then referring to that with the addEventListener.

let id = email.id;
element.addEventListener('click', () => show_email(id));

Comment: I'm not talking about the id of the "email". I'm talking about the ids of the DOM nodes you're generating in the `for...of...` loop: `<div id="emails-item"><span id="emails-address">...</span><span id="emails-subject">...</span><span id="emails-timestamp">...</span></div>`